# Difference between 17 digits timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp

Currently, I am working with `UTC+02:00` timezone in Node.js. **I would like to take the difference between two 17 digits timestamp**. For example, I have a two timestamp: `20180712080000000 (YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSS)` i.e. `2018/07/12 10:00:00 000` and `20180712060000000 (YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSS)` i.e. `2018/07/12 08:00:00 000`. If I will take the difference between these two timestamps then output could be `20000000` (actually it should be 2 hrs). If I will convert the difference of two timestamps i.e. `20000000` to hours then answer is `5.56` hrs but it should be `2` hrs.

Am I missing something?

Kindly feel free to correct me.

So far I tried:

```
let starttime = 20180712060000000; // UTC + 2
let endtime =   20180712080000000; // UTC + 2
console.log("Difference is ",endtime-starttime);
```

Comment: That's not how you build timestamps!

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I know but the mentioned timestamp is compatible in my current project so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must work with that kind of timestamps (17 character long strings) you could convert them to Date objects like this:

```js
    var date1 = '20180712060000000'
    var date2 = '20180712080000000'

    function timestampToDate(dateString) {
      return new Date(dateString.substring(0, 4), 
        parseInt(dateString.substring(4, 6)) - 1, 
        dateString.substring(6, 8), 
        dateString.substring(8, 10), 
        dateString.substring(10, 12), 
        dateString.substring(12, 14), 
        dateString.substring(14, 16))
    }

    var date1Object = timestampToDate(date1)
    var date2Object = timestampToDate(date2)
    
    var difference = Math.abs(date1Object - date2Object) // this will hold the difference in milliseconds
    var differenceInHours = difference / 36e5
    
    console.log(differenceInHours)
```

To avoid having to dissect the string like that you could consider using a time library like moment (https://momentjs.com/)

With moment you could do something like this:

```
var date1 = moment('20180712060000000', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSS')
var date2 = moment('20180712080000000', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSS')

var difference = moment.duration(date1 - date2).hours()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am using the `moment.js` library. Is there any easy to do with the `moment.js` library? I couldn't able to find.

Comment: For you updated answer `moment.js`: Could you please check it again? I am getting `TypeError: (date2 - date1).duration is not a function` error.

Comment: Yup sorry I had an error, I updated and tested it now ;)

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution!

Comment: Whoops... you need to subtract one from month (month is zero-based)

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you use aren't valid timestamps.

The timestamp you can provide to the `Date` constructor is the number of milliseconds since Epoch.

You can get it from a date using `date.getTime()`:

```
let starttime = new Date("2018-07-12T06:00:00").getTime(); // assuming local TZ
```

Comment: It means I need to do `console.log("Difference is ",endtime.getTime()-starttime.getTime());` Am I correct?

Comment: This difference will be a number of milliseconds. For 2 hours it's `720000`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But how can I convert `20180712060000000` to `2018-07-12T06:00:00`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this library](https://momentjs.com/) for clean and better code.